# Play audio when model renders in Vuforia for Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to play a sound clip when an object is rendered in Vuforia. I found a [solution](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/adding-audio-file-target#comment-2029395) in Vuforia forums for this but is not working for me, in fact Unity crahes.

The solutions consist in altering the file **\Assets\Vuforia\Scripts\DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs** from Vuforia's source code:

```
private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

    // *** Additional Audio code 
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        child.audio.Play();
    }

    // Enable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = true;
    }

    // Enable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = true;
    }

    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
}


private void OnTrackingLost()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

    // *** Additional Audio code
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        child.audio.Stop();
    }

    // Disable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    // Disable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
}
```

It just adds **child.audio.Play();** to be called on **OnTrackingFound()** and **child.audio.Stop();** to be called on **OnTrackingLost()**

This should work in theory, I added the audio file as a child for the Image Target, but because '**Component.audio**' has been deprecated I had to change it to **`GetComponent<AudioSource>()`** instead. So the code ended like this:

```
    // *** Additional Audio code
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        child.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
```

And

```
    // *** Additional Audio code
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        child.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
    }
```

Why is it not working?

Did I used **`GetComponent<AudioSource>()`** wrong?

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple alternative to this. Add the audiosource to the object and make sure play on awake and loop is checked.

And on tracking found set your gameobject active true, on tracking lost set it to false.

Comment: This is not working for me. Irrespective of the detection state, the audio is always played.

Comment: Did you make this audiosource object child of the target. You need to turn it on and off using imagtreacking found and imagtreacking lost functions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the help of the previous answer. I added the audio resource to the 3D object with Play on Awake checked. Then I make the audio play **OnTrackingFound()** accessing the child of the Image Targer, and doing the opposite **OnTrackingLost()**. The code ended like this:

```
private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

    // Enable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
            component.enabled = true;
    }

    // Enable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = true;
    }

    // SOLUTION
    if (mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>() != null)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
}


private void OnTrackingLost()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

    // Disable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    // Disable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    // SOLUTION
    if (mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>() != null)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>().Stop();
    }
    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
}
```